# Data update conflict in SPO by Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, modern-team-site

I'm using Modern experience in SharePoint Online.
What happens if I update the data by Power Automate while another user editing the data in SharePoint (as well as editing in the grid view)?
This means what happens if two users update the same data at the same time.
I would appreciate with any idea or opinion.

Answer (score 0):

How did you update the data by Power Automate while editing the data in grid view?

Usually, after saving the changes in the list grid view, the flow will be triggered later.

-------------------Update----------------------

If you are worrying about conflict, as a workaround, we could add a delay in flow to avoid data update conflict.

[image]

Comment: For example, I'm trying to update a list item by Power Automate and want to know what happens if another user is opening edit mode with that item.

Comment: If the user just opens the edit mode without making any changes, the flow will not be triggered, and if the user changes the value, the flow will be triggered again.

Comment: I haven't heard of triggers. I'm asking what happens if two users update the same data at the same time.

Comment: It is not easy for two users to update the same data at the same time. The flwo will update the data sequentially.

Comment: It's very easy. User1 is opening Edit mode, then Just update that data with Power Automate.

Comment: So when User1 is opening Edit mode, how did you trigger the flow to update the data?Manually or When the list item has been modified? or other triggers?

Comment: User1 is opening Edit mode for data1, then User2 manually run Flow for data1.

Comment: Please see the updated reply.